# What's wrong with this javascript sort

Tags: javascript

I'm not getting the sort results I expect.  What's wrong.

Here's the code:

```
data.sort(function(a,b){
  return (Date.parse(a) - Date.parse(b));
});
for(var j = 0; j < data.length; j++){
  var item = data[j];
  console.log(j+") " +item.createdAt+":"+Date.parse(item.createdAt));
}
```

And here's the output:

```
0) Fri Jun 10 2016 16:58:26 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time):1465592306000
1) Tue Jun 07 2016 08:07:34 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time):1465301254000
2) Fri Jun 10 2016 15:57:44 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time):1465588664000
3) Fri Jun 10 2016 14:34:45 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time):1465583685000
4) Fri Jun 10 2016 14:22:02 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time):1465582922000
5) Fri Jun 10 2016 11:14:34 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time):1465571674000
6) Fri Jun 10 2016 10:03:56 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time):1465567436000
7) Fri Jun 10 2016 10:02:58 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time):1465567378000
8) Thu Jun 09 2016 16:32:29 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time):1465504349000
9) Thu Jun 09 2016 16:29:24 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time):1465504164000
```

Comment: Wat did you expect?

Comment: You need `return (Date.parse(a.createdAt) - Date.parse(b.createdAt));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `data` is array of **object** and each object contains the `createdAt` property on which the array should be sorted, you need

```
data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (Date.parse(a.createdAt) - Date.parse(b.createdAt));
});
```

If the data is coming from server database, I'll suggest to get the data sorted on the date from the Database itself.

Answer (score 0):

Tushar hit it on the head, if that is what you're looking to sort on.  If you want to go further in depth about sorting on a particular value comparison you'll want to research the array prototype.  You can find that here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort